# How to Post data and one file to action with a ajax requset

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase, jquery-ajaxq

i want send a multi parameter with a ajax request . 
for example : id=1,name="amin",logo:file .
id type is int and Name type is String and Logo Type is HttpPostfileBase in my action .

```
var ID = $("#OfficeId").val();
if (ID == "") {
  var imagefile1 = $("#fileInput")[0].files[0];
  alert(imagefile1.name);
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Administration")',
    data: { ID: ID, Name: $("#Name").val(), ManagerName: $("#ManageName").val(), UserName: $("#UserName").val(), Password: $("#Password").val(), Address: $("#Address").val(), Wage: $("#Wage").val(), Logo: imagefile1 },
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function (result) {           
      if (result.Success) {
        alert(result);
      }
      eval(result.Script);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("خطا!");
    }
  });
}
```

But this Code Not Work For Me. if i remove Logo(a file parameter) from ajax request, Request is work Fine. My Problem is Just Logo(a file Parameter).

Comment: with ajax request it's difficult to achieve this. you can better use some plugins like "jquery form" http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object

Comment: can you add your controller code also ? have you checked in debugging mode that you are receiving image file in ajax call data block or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the concept of FormData object of javascript like below:

You can give to the formData all form for processing

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('ID', $("#OfficeId").val());
formData.append('Name', $("#Name").val());
formData.append('image', $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]);
```

Ajax request with jQuery will looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function (result) {

                if (result.Success) {
                   alert(result);
                }
                eval(result.Script);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("خطا!");
            }

})
```

Comment: #somprabhsharma i change My code to your code but Ajax request can not call create action.?!

Comment: i get error from js file : Jquery.js

Comment: work for me. Thank You

Comment: Please mark it as an answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a button first** : click event of this fuction will send value of id to ajax call & you will get data based on ID value.

```
<button type="button" onclick="Edit(@model.ID)">Edit</button>
```

**Edit(ID) function :**

```
 function Edit(Get_Id) {
    var name1 = $('#ID1').val();  // save required values to send to another file
    var name2 = $('#ID2').val();

    $.ajax({

        method: 'Post',
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit","Home")', // method name & controller name.
        data: { id: Get_Id, Column_Name1: name1, Column_Name2: name2}, // bind data to column names and send to method.
        success: function () {
            alert("Data Sent")
        }
    })
}
```